# Add second table value through foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-database-first

I'm creating a website of elearn, I'm using database first model, and I'm using stored procedure for data inserting or updating. But my teacher says not to use stored procedure, only used basic mvc function.

Now I have a problem, I have a registration form that takes email or password or as well a teacher or student role, role is a boolean value which is true for teacher or false for student.

When I click fill the form or clicked on submit button it add userinfo, but question is how to add add value in student or teacher table when press on submit button with basic function.

This is my code with stored procedure:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(tbl_UserInfo user)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new ELearnDataBase())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (cmd.Parameters != null)
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                    if (cs.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        cs.Open();

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.insertintoInfo", cs); //Table1
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.Email);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", user.Pwd);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", user.Role);

                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    {
                        //db.SaveChanges();

                        if (user.Role)    // teacher
                        {
                            var modell = db.tbl_UserInfo
                                          .Where(r => r.Email.Equals(user.Email) && r.Pwd.Equals(user.Pwd))
                                          .First();

                            cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddAddress", cs); //Table1
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", modell.Id);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postalCode", 0);

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddCourse", cs); //Table1
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", modell.Id);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fee", 0.00);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_class", "");

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.insertintoTeacherInfo", cs); //Table1
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", modell.Id);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rank", "");

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            cs.Close();
                        }
                        else   //student 
                        {
                            var modell = db.tbl_UserInfo
                                           .Where(r => r.Email.Equals(user.Email) && r.Pwd.Equals(user.Pwd))
                                           .First();

                            cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddAddress", cs); //Table1
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", modell.Id);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postalCode", 0);

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                             cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.insertintoStudentInfo", cs); //Table1
                             cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", modell.Id);
                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roll", @DateTime.Now.Year + " ElearnWeb"+""+modell.Id);

                             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                             cs.Close();
                         }

                         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                     }      //return "Done";
                     else 
                     {
                          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                     }

                     // return "Failed";
                 }
                 catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Invalid Statement", e);
                 }

                 cs.Close();

                 // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is not correct");
         }
     }
     catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
     {
         foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
             eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);

             foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
             }
          }

          throw;
      }

      return View();
}
```

Without using stored procedure:

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(tbl_UserInfo user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            using (ElearnDataBase db = new ElearnDataBase())
            {

                db.tbl_UserInfo.Add(user);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

                if (user.Role)//teacher
                {


                    var modell =
                                       db.tbl_UserInfo
                                        .Where(r => r.Email.Equals(user.Email) && r.Pwd.Equals(user.Pwd))
                                        .First();


                }
                else//student 
                {

                    var modell =
                                       db.tbl_UserInfo
                                        .Where(r => r.Email.Equals(user.Email) && r.Pwd.Equals(user.Pwd))
                                        .First();






                }





        }


        return View(user);
    }
```

This is my db relationship diagram:

[elearn relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPGR2.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the MVC way to do it. You do the database related things in Models and only the logics in the Controllers.

Have a look at this code from my Point Of Sale project.

**This code is from class Products which is a Model class.**

```
    public bool SaveNewProduct(string name, int unitid, int catid, int compid, float salerate, float purchaserate, int openingamout)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Products (pname,punitid,pcategoryid,pcompanyid,psalerate,purchaserate,openingamount) VALUES('" + name + "'," + unitid + "," + catid + "," + compid + "," + salerate + ","+purchaserate+"," + openingamout + ")";
        int temp = dal.Create(query);
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**DAL class:**

```
    public int Create(string query)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        int returnVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return returnVal;
    }
```

**The controller part:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewProduct(string name, string unit, string category, string company, String salerate, string purchaserate, string openingamount)
{
    // You perform the validations first which I am not including.
    // If all validations are good, then you call the add method from the Products model

    Products p = new Products();
    bool check = p..SaveNewProduct(name, unitid, catid, compid, srate, prate, oamount);

    if (check)
    {
    ViewBag.MessageType = "Success";
    ViewBag.Message = "New Product added";
    }
}
```

This is how you do the MVC way. You perform the DB things in Models and do the logics in Controller.

**The AddNewProduct() form Products and Create() from DAL contains all the things you need to know to about inserting in database without stored procedures**

You may have a [look at this](https://github.com/devWaleed/.NET-Model-Essentials/blob/master/Model.cs) as well if you're interested. You can inherit this Model class to your own Models and get some basic functionality.

Comment: you again used store procedure sir , i just said how to add the value in student or teacher table when click on submit

Comment: I am not using stored procedure, I created an SQL statement for that. On button click check if the form was submitted for teacher of student then run that query from the Model